# Compare ObjectName of PushButton in qt

Tags: c++, qt

In QT I want to compare the text set on a push-button in an if statement. for eg: If I have set the text on a pushbutton to be "Stop". what method or function do I use to compare the text set on the push button. All of it is in QT C++.

Comment: The question has been correctly answered, so I only add a note: Implementing a logic based on UI labels and texts is not a good practice. It is a very fragile and hard to maintain design.

Answer (score 0):

That would be [`QAbstractPushButton::text()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractbutton.html#text-prop).

For example:

```
QPushButton button{"Hello"};
assert(button.text() == "Hello");
```